# What model is this Stronglight crankset?

Tags: crankset

This Stronglight triple crank is stamped **G4** at the pedal end, and (less clearly) **44B** at the BB end.

I need to find a corresponding left crank to go with the right one that I have. Even if I can't find exactly the original partner, I'd like to be able to look for one that's as similar as possible.

[image: Stronglight triple crank G4 44B]
[image: Stronglight triple crank G4 44B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the arms are Stronglight 99: source [one](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=D7367238-36F7-472B-8A7E-C1DA6C978034&Enum=115&AbsPos=37) and [two](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=38CB59E2-F7AF-42C5-BBC1-B47DD4208732&Enum=115&AbsPos=38). I was not able to find other arms with the same spider recess pattern.